# Change bootstrap layout on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/a4cbvzj7/1/

Super simple bootstrap layout, two col, image on top text on bottom.

At mobile size I want text on top image on bottom.

Can I do this with push pull or do I need to have two layouts and hide and show them on desktop, mobile.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <p class="text">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you've provided isn't in a two column layout, but I can figure out what you need.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-md-push-6">
      <p class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-md-pull-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want to learn more then look at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid 
and checkout column ordering

Comment: I see what you mean, they weren't actually columns next to each other but they were set to 12 so they sit on top of each other which is the way I want them. Your layout has them next to each other.

Comment: You could do through either hidden-xs class for mobile to hide a certain class and hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg for the class you want to hide on desktop and tablet. As the push and pull will only work on column classes that allow multiple columns within a row.

Comment: Or you could do a small javascript statement that will be able to identify the browser width is less than 767px and re-position a class before

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply using media query like

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
 .row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
  } 
}
```

updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a4cbvzj7/11/)